# How to read an array and analyse the input

Tags: c

I was just wondering is there some way to read an array and then based upon the letters entered do something?

Like for example: if the roman numeral; MM was entered is there some way to see that 2 M's were entered and display the value for M?

output would be: 1000+1000.

Could you just tell me the name of the function, because it is for an assignment I dont want someone doing it for me, I just dont know where to start from.

example: `char romanNumerals[2] = {"MMMCMXCVIII"};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char romanNumerals[2] = {"MMMCMXCVIII"};
```

Is not right as it can only hold 1 element(+1 for the `\0`). Change it to

```
char romanNumerals[] = "MMMCMXCVIII";
```

The compiler will choose the correct size for the array when doing the above initialization.

Then,you need a variable to add the sum of each roman number. So create

```
int sum=0;
```

And you need to loop the length of array times as you want to check each letter.

```
int i,len=strlen(romanNumerals);
for(i = 0;i < len;i++)
{
//body of for loop
}
```

`string.h` should be included in order to use `strlen` function which returns the length of a string.

Now,check each letter inside the body of the `for` loop using

```
if(romanNumerals[i]=='M')
    sum=sum+1000;
else if(romanNumerals[i]=='C')
    sum=sum+/*the corresponding value*/;
else if(...)
    sum=sum+/*value*/;
//etc etc
```

And then at last,print `sum`.

Comment: Never call strlen from inside a loop condition, especially not when teaching beginners.

Comment: I've edited that. All that does is reduce the performance of the program right?

Comment: yah i was working on it in class and i figured it out, so i had to create a separate function, pretty much what you just explain.

the body of the function:
for(a = 0; s[a]!= '\0'; a++){
  if(s[a] == 'M'){
   result += 1000;
  }
and I just do that for each roman numeral.

Comment: It is much easier to work out the value by starting at the back of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the  `scanf` function from `stdio.h`.

```
char str[3];
scanf("%s", str);
```

would store up to two characters from the standard input and the null terminator (`\0`)  into the `char` array pointed at by `str`.

Comment: Nope. You need space for the `\0` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers are correct, but keep in mind that if you just sum the input letters with a lookup (M=1000, C=100, X=10, V=5, I=1), having "MMMCMXCVIII" would mean 3000+100+1000+10+100+5+3 = 4218 and this is not what "MMMCMXCVIII" means in roman numerals (it actually means 3998 ).

Answer (score 0):

For reasons explained in the link supplied by NSimon (see 1st comment) `scanf()` is not the best option when the input string length isn't known.

Other options are `fgets()` and `getline()`. The thing to remember is that a properly formed string is terminated by a null character - usually written '\0'. Hence if all else fails, you can always read char for char using the `fgetc()` function in a loop of some sort and stop when either your buffer is full or the '\0' is found.

So much for reading the array. When it comes to evaluating roman numerals, the best approach is to start at the back. Roman numerals have a (niot quite so simple) ordering:

I < V < X < L < C < D < M

Reading backwards you need to follow some straight forward rules:

- The least significant packet is always last (i.e. IXL is wrong, it should be LIX = 59)
- If X or V is preceeded by I then subract 1 otherwise add the value.
- If L or C is preceeded by X then subtract 10 otherwise add the value.
- If D or M is preceeded by C then subtract 100 otherwise add the value.

Note that M & D can only ever be preceeded by C or M. L & C can only be preceeded by X or C. X & V can only be preceeded by I or X. Anything else indicates a malformed number.

Thus working from the back it should be reasonably easy to obtain the correct value.